# Tab event not firing for default tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 tabs, of which 1 is active when the page loads. I have associated an event with the tabs. The code is given below:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class='active'><a href="#id1" data-toggle="tab" id="q0" class="qtab"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#id2" data-toggle="tab" id="q1" class="qtab"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#id3" data-toggle="tab" id="q2" class="qtab"></a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.qtab').on("shown.bs.tab", function(event){
    var elem = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(elem);
});
```

The alert box is displayed when the tab is changed, but not when the default tab (ID 'q0') is displayed. Does anyone know how I can fire the event for the default tab as well? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does it happen with `show.bs.tab` as well?

Comment: please a sample on plunkr or jsfiddle i will resolve it

Comment: @Stef yes, I tried it with that, now that you said it. It had the same result.

Comment: Weird, well I got it working in this fiddle, though without seeing all of your code I can't really tell you what has changed: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11340/

Comment: @Stef That worked for me as well, but did that alert box show for the first tab when the page loaded. The first tab is the default tab, so when the page opens shouldn't the alert box show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap documentation for [Tab Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events):

> shown.bs.tab: (on the newly-active just-shown tab, the same one as for the show.bs.tab event)

You have to dig around for the subtext here, but it looks like this event is only fired on an active tab change. To get around this, remove the `active` class from your first tab (because the event also won't be fired if the tab is already active) and set the active tab in your jQuery on page load with the following line (also from the Bootstrap documentation):

```
$('.nav a[href="#id1"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
```

See my [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11341/) for demonstration.